# Reuse percent sign in Makefile prerequesite as subdirectory name

Tags: bash, unix, makefile

I'd like to learn how to re-use the % sign in my makefile target's prequisite, supposing that the target is `X.pdf`, and the prerequesite is in `X/X.tex`.

To elaborate, I currently have a makefile like so:

```
all: foo.pdf

%.pdf: %.tex
    pdflatex $*.tex
```

I additionally have a file `foo.tex`, and when I type `make` it will make `foo.pdf` by running `pdflatex foo.tex`.

Now for various reasons I can't control, my directory structure has changed:

```
my_dir
|- Makefile
|- foo
   |- foo.tex
```

I'd like to modify my Makefile such that when it tries to make `X.pdf`, it looks for the file `X/X.tex`.

I tried the following (I tried to put '%/%.tex' to tell it to look for `foo/foo.tex`):

```
all: foo.pdf

%.pdf: %/%.tex
    pdflatex $*/$*.tex
```

However, this yields:

```
No rule to make target `foo.pdf', needed by `all'. Stop.
```

So does `%.pdf: $*/$*.tex`.

If I change the `%/%.tex` to `foo/%.tex` it works as expected, but I don't want to hard-code the `foo` in there, because in the future I'll do `all: foo.pdf bar.pdf` and it should look for `foo/foo.tex` and `bar/bar.tex`.

I'm fairly new to Makefiles (experience limited to modifying someone else's to my needs), and have never done a more-than-absolutely basic one, so if anyone could give me a pointer that would help (I don't really know what words to search for in the Makefile documentation - the only ones that looked promising were `%` and `$*`, which I couldn't get to work).

Comment: This is harder than it should be; handling wildcards is one of the things Make is remarkably bad at. It can be done, but it's ugly, so if @wisent's solution is good enough for your purposes, you should probably go with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use VPATH to specify a list of directories that make should search.

exemplary makefile:

```
# Find all tex files
tex := $(shell find -iname '*.tex')

# Make targets out of them
PDFS := $(notdir $(tex:%.tex=%.pdf))
# specify search folder
VPATH := $(dir $(tex))

all : $(PDFS)

%.pdf : %.tex
        pdflatex $<
```

or even better would be to use vpath (lowercase):

```
vpath %.tex $(dir $(tex))
```

it will look only for .tex files in those directories.

Comment: This will work well enough if there is no `foo.tex` but `foo/foo.tex`. If there is a `./foo.tex` or `bar/baz/foo.tex` lying around, you'll have trouble.

Comment: Luckily I won't have that problem (all my %.tex are guaranteed to be in a folder %). This works for my purposes (although I was surprised that you can't just use `$*` etc in a Makefile's prerequisite, I assumed my difficulties were due to being a Makefile novice). Cheers!

Comment: You can use `$*` IFF (a) you have a sufficiently new version of GNU make, (b) you enable the .SECONDEXPANSION special target, and (c) you escape them as `$$*`.  See the GNU make manual for documentation on secondary expansion.

Comment: @MadScientist; could we see a solution using the technique you're describing here? It seems interesting, and might show off a few advanced Make techniques